# Is it normal to have higher cross validation score IN EACH ITERATION than testing score

Tags: cross-validation, average-precision

I'm using 10 fold stratified cross validation, training:testing is 0.75:0.25. Balanced data.
I'm using cross validation when doing feature selection with the 0.75 training data. The score I'm using is sklearn "average_precision_score", and got values between 0.78 and 0.9 **in each iteration**.

Finally with selected features, I'm using the 0.25 testing data to predict, got average_precision_score around 0.76.

I'm wondering is this overfitting or normal.
I think each iteration of cross validation has smaller data sample while my testing data has larger size than each CV iteration, therefore this should be normal.
**But what do you think?**

NOTE: At this moment, I haven't added param tuning methods. I will do that later. I think param tuning is not relevant yo my question here.

Comment: CV usually has higher scores, also there could very well be some overfitting.